# Open file from npm module from executable

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have npm module ([@jcubic/lips](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jcubic/lips)) that have executable and I want to open file that is located in that module directory. The module is installed globally.

I want to access file `../examples/helpers.lips` relative to bin directory in my module but executable is installed in /usr/bin/lips and I don't know how to access the module.

How can I access that file, or get root directory of the module? Is there cross platform solution?

My executable is lisp interpreter and I'm executing this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lips

(load "../examples/helpers.lips")
```

which is understandable because CWD is directory from which I invoked the script. Load is just fs.readFile + eval.

My interpreter is written in JavaScript so require work the same as in Node and every function accessed in node can be accessed in lips. But I want to load that file first have have important functions and macros. In the future it maye be loaded by default but first I need to access the module. It would be nice if it also work when called from node_module installed locally or as source from git repo.

Recently I've learnt that you can use require with text files if you add handler is this the only way to get access to static files inside a module (use `require("@jcubic/lips/examples/helpers.lips")` or is better way). Will try to use that undocumented feature if I find the article about this, and update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution in Node.js docs for [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) which is function `require.resolve`.

function description says:

> Use the internal require() machinery to look up the location of a module, but rather than loading the module, just return the resolved filename.

so it was exactly what I've needed, This is my function I was using, run this before I evaluate user code:

```
function boostrap() {
    var path;
    try {
        path = require.resolve('./examples/helpers.lips');
    } catch (e) {
        path = require.resolve('@jcubic/lips/examples/helpers.lips');
    }
    var data = fs.readFileSync(path);
    return run(data, env);
}
```