# How to use static assets with npm module executable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is there any way to have executable in Node.js NPM module (exectuable is located in completely different place than the module), to have additional file (or directory with files) that the exectutable can access?

This is same problem as in [Open file from npm module from executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564177/open-file-from-npm-module-from-executable) but phrased differently, I have REPL and I want to load files that are in the module from which executable came from.

This should be simple and common task but I'm not able to find solution, maybe you know some package that have binary with assets, looking at the source I would be able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to do that when needed this again. Looking at [docs for module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options)

I've found function:

require.resolve(request[, options])

> Use the internal require() machinery to look up the location of a module, but rather than loading the module, just return the resolved filename.

so to load static assets you only need this:

```
function boostrap() {
    var path;
    try {
        path = require.resolve('./examples/helpers.lips');
    } catch (e) {
        path = require.resolve('@jcubic/lips/examples/helpers.lips');
    }
    var data = fs.readFileSync(path);
    return run(data, env);
}
```

I need to test two cases and if I can that funciton with module name and I have the source code it will throw the same as if I call as local file and I'm not in source.